# Is this a good implementation of user_params strong parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def user_params
  if current_user.admin?
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :student, :admin)
  else
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password) 
  end                           
end
```

I would like admins to be able to update users' roles.

Users_params is a strong parameter to prevent hackers from changing users' roles.

The below code is insecure, correct? I see this code all over GitHub.

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :student, :admin)                         
end
```

Comment: Before updating user "params.permit!" so that it will allow you to update..

Comment: Your first solution mentioned above is correct. You should always permit ONLY the attributes you are allowing to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def user_params
  if current_user.admin?
    params.require(:user).permit!
  else
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password) 
  end                           
end
```

Comment: Who said admin should be able to change all user params?